# Prestashop nginx Categories 404

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, server, prestashop

i try to configure my Prestashop with nginx.
Everything works except the categories. I have some friendly URL Rewrite:

{categories:/}{rewrite}/

Like: myurl.com/fuellmaterial/

Nginx give me a 404 for that category sites. The problem is that the server add "index.html" to the url, i can see that in the error.log

Error   404 GET /fuellmaterial/ HTTP/1.1    SSL/TLS-Zugriff für nginx

Error   15130#0: *1295 "/var/www/vhosts/myurl.com/httpdocs/fuellmaterial/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)                nginx-Fehler

How can i remove that index.html for categories? Any Ideas?

thanks

Comment: Which version do you use ?

Comment: nginx/1.11.10 and PS 1.6.1.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration should work as it is on our PHP 7 / Nginx / Presta 1.6 production configuration, don't forget to uncomment and edit for your needs like SSL configuration :

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    #listen *:443 ssl;
    #ssl_certificate /root/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
    #ssl_certificate_key /root/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.domain.tld/privkey.pem;

    server_name www.domain.tld;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.domain.tld.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.domain.tld.error.log;

    root /var/www/www.domain.tld;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    client_max_body_size 60M;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;

    rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
    rewrite ^/images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ /js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404;

    #ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    #ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    #ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    #ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    #ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:RSA+3DES:AES128-SHA:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    #ssl_stapling on;
    #ssl_stapling_verify on;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;

    resolver 127.0.0.1;
    location ~* \.(eot|ttf|woff|eof|woff2|css|js|jsonp|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|svg|webm|mp3|mp4)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        # ~ 10 Days
        expires 604800s;
    }

    location ~ \.tpl {
        deny all;
    }


    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {

        fastcgi_index index.php;

        include fcgi.conf;
        # depending on version, could be : include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    }

}
```

Comment: great it works, i am not sure which code exactly the one for the solution, but it works now. thank you very much